# Powershell ассоциация значений в хэш таблицах

Tags: powershell

Имеются 2 хэш таблицы ($table1 - id пользователя и id руководителя, $table2 - id и ФИО)

$table1

Name     Value
----     -----
id_user1 id_head1
id_user2 id_head2

$table2

Name     Value
----     -----
id_user1 fio1
id_user2 fio2
id_head1 fio3
id_head2 fio4

Необходимо сформировать таблицу $table3, чтобы для всех значений $table1 подставились ФИО из $table2.

$table3

Name     Value
----     -----
fio1 fio3
fio2 fio4

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `$table3 = $table1.GetEnumerator() | % { $h = @{ } } { $h.Add($table2[$_.Key], $table2[$_.Value]) } { $h }`

Answer (score -1):

`$table3 = $table1.GetEnumerator() | % { $h = @{ } } { $h.Add($table2[$_.Key], $table2[$_.Value]) } { $h }`